# Turbo Encoder inter-leaver not working

Tags: matlab, encoder, telecommunication, forwarderrorcorrection

I am trying to create a turbo encoder for my project.

Till now i have created the convolution encoder of 1/2 rate. Now i am having difficulty to apply interleaver. Here is my code. I am not getting output in ilvr. Correct me where i am going incorrect. Thanks in advance

```
msg = [0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1];
t= poly2trellis(3,[6 7]);
[isok,status] = istrellis(t);
code1 = convenc(msg,t);
ilvr = randperm(msg);
code2 = convenc(ilvr,t);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, firstly, if your question is about `ilvr` then why include the rest of the code other than the definition of `msg` and the line in question?

Secondly, when I ran this:

```
msg = [0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1];
ilvr = randperm(msg);
```

I got the following error:

```
Error using randperm
Size inputs must be scalar.
```

So, this means the the input is not what `randperm` was expecting. Then I typed `help randperm`, and looked at the help for `randperm`, so now I understand what `randperm` does and what inputs it expects. The error is because you gave `randperm` a vector, but the first input must be an integer.

I'm not sure what you are trying to do on that line, maybe you are trying to get a random permutation of the elements in `msg`? Following a hint in the help page, try this:

```
ilvr=msg(randperm(numel(msg)));
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Actually i am trying to build a turbo encoder. It encodes the msg using 2 parallel convolution encoders. Out of which one encoder encodes the msg after the msg is interleaved. Hence i was using randperm() function.